# What is the type I have to pass to constructor

Tags: php

I have two class in PHP, in one of then a execute a sql sentences and now I want to pass the result of the sentences to the other class

I have this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($objeto) > 0){
  while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($objeto)){
    $result[]=$obj;
 }
```

I now I try to pass $result to the other class

For this I create a new instance of the class, and pass the value

```
$generar= new DataInjector( $result);
```

and the constructor of the class
I have this.

```
function __construct(object $data) {
  print_r("ff");
}
```

What is the value´s type that a I have to pass?

I try, array, object, resources... but nothing work!

Any idea

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Comment: why not `var_dump($data)` in the constructor to see how it's coming out? You are building an ARRAY of objects, so coercing to an overall object doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you don't have to add a type hint, but here it would be `array`.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea this happens sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with (since `$result` is an array):

```
function __construct(array $data) {
    print_r("ff");
}
```

...but it's not required.

Comment: mysql_fetch_object() returns class.
mysql_fetch_array() returns array

Comment: @Nick Have a look at the code: `$result[]=$obj;` --> it's an array

Comment: my mistake, but my answer is still valid

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_object() returns object (class).

constructor of the other class must looks like this:

```
function __construct($data) {
  print_r("ff");
}
```

the specifying of type in PHP 5.4+ helps for finding mistakes only if you have base type and extend-ed types.

Something like this (code will not work)

```
class Figure{
...
}

class Square extends Figure{
...
}

function do_something(Figure $f){
}
```

the function do_something() can be called with Figure, with Square, but not with different class that do not extends Figure.